# How to create dynamic table using Ajax success

Tags: php, html, jquery, laravel

I am trying to make a dynamic table from my database data, but I'm having a problem and I honestly don't know what to do next.

I used this code with static table and it works perfectly fine but with dynamic table, it never work.

Here's my code in my blade file **layout** with id = **informationmodal**.

```
<table id="employee">
 <tr>
  <td>ID Type</td>
  <td>ID Number</td>
 </tr>
 @foreach ($users as $user)
  <tr>
   <td>{{ $user->id_type }}</td>
   <td>{{ $user->id_number }}</td>
  </tr>
 @endforeach
</table>
```

and here's my Ajax function from other blade file.

```
    $(document).on('click', '.showdata', function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            url: "/search/"+id+"/searchInfo",
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(html){
                $('#informationmodal').modal('show');
            }
            
        })
    });
```

and this my code from my controller

```
public function searchInfo($id)
{
    if(request()->ajax())
    {
        $users = myModal::select('*')->where('fk_emp_id','=', $id)->firstOrFail();
        return response()->json(['users' => $users]);
    }
}
```

it gives me an error of **$users is undefined**

So if anyone can help me this problem will be much appreciated or is there any other way to solve my problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please debug the $id value, and manually set a value for the $id and check the output

Comment: @DebasisRath I just did, but I can't run my laravel app because of this error ($users is undefined).

Comment: If you're using this searchInfo  function for viewing table data then it will not work because it has ajax request with response , you need to append through the ajax call

Comment: @RushikeshGanesh can you show me please?

Answer (score 0):

it's just for the Understanding purpose only

**Controller Code**

```
  public function index($id){
    $users = myModal::select('*')->where('fk_emp_id','=', $id)->firstOrFail();
    return view('admin.table',compact('users'));
  }
```

Here is the index function which passes data to your blade file

**Blade file**

```
<table id="employee">
 <tr>
   <td>ID Type</td>
   <td>ID Number</td>
 </tr>
@foreach ($users as $user)
<tr>
   <td>{{ $user->id_type }}</td>
   <td>{{ $user->id_number }}</td>
 </tr>
 @endforeach
```

**For Ajax Response**

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: "/search/"+id+"/searchInfo",
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data){
           //append the respose as per your requriement 
        }
    })
  })
```

Comment: I understand what you mean but it doesn't apply to my problem. I appreciate your time and effort. Thank you!